# Подсказки по коду xml в Android Studio перестали работать

Tags: android-studio, android-xml, settings

Я всего пару месяцев как осваиваю Java/Android Studio,так что попрошу не кидаться помидорами.

Столкнулся с проблемой, что в коде xml нет возможности посмотреть какие атрибуты элементов графического интерфейса IDE может предложить.

Да и вообще подсказки как таковые ПОЧТИ не работают, кроме некоторых (на втором скриншоте).

В java коде с подсказками всё хорошо. К слову, они перестали работать после установки и удаления плагина Power Mode II (но это не точно).

Что мною было сделано:

- проверка настроек Inspections(включен Lint и вообще всё по Android и Java, остальные по умолчанию)
- Power Save Mode отключён
- удалял папку .idea в проекте
- чистил кэш .gradle
- проверил настройки редактора в Code Completion
- переустанавливал студию.

Ничего из вышеперечисленного не помогло. Теперь надеюсь на помощь коллективного разума.

Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[![]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scqwo.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scqwo.png)

UP. Добавлю два скрина: первый как должно быть, второй - как у меня.[image: как должно быть]

[image: как у меня]

UP2. Вот так стоит, ситуация та же. Insert selection - пробовал и включенным и выключенным,но без результатов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UP3. Скрин кода xml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если мне не изменяет память, то в xml при тех условиях которые вы показали никакой подсказки не будет

Comment: Поправлю свой вопрос, добавлю два скрина: один - как ДОЛЖНО быть, второй - как у меня.

Comment: перейдите в настройки и там введите в поиске suggest и там дальше editor-code completion у меня стоит галочка show suggestion as you type, и подсказки работают нормально

Comment: Чекнул. Попробовал. Не помогло, в вопросе добавил UP2 со скрином.

Comment: все скриншоты с одного пк?

Comment: Именно, что с одного. Но тот, который показывает КАК должно отображаться -  с видео.

Comment: я просто подумал что у вас где-то работают подсказки, а где-то нет

Comment: может библиотеки не подтянулись, у вас в xml все подключено?

Comment: Подсказки работают в java коде. В xml нет.

Comment: покажите весь xml пожалуйста

Comment: добавил в вопросе

Answer (score 2):

подтверждаю, снижение compileSdk с 33 до 32 решает проблему подсказок.
А на 33 просит перейти, так как меняем на 1.9.0
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'

тут ставим 1.8.0 и все рабоатет огонь

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй следующее:
Вариант 1:
Зайди в File->Invalidate Caches / Restart и нажми кнопку Invalidate and Restart

Вариант 2:
1. Выключи AndroidStudio
2. Удали все файлы из папки с кешом: C:\Users\ "Твое имя Пользователя"
\ .AndroidStudio4.0\system\caches

Answer (score -1):

Появилась такая же проблема при повышении версии compileSdk
Проблему решил понижением compileSdk до версии 32 (у меня была 33)

В файле build.gradle:
compileSdk=32